# Android Studio Kotlin Multiplatform project has messed up auto-complete

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am building a Kotlin Multiplatform project in Android Studio, and the auto-complete for the common libraries that I am using is not working, but it builds in Gradle just fine.

I've tried:

- invalidating the IDE's caches and restarting
- cleaning my build
- closing and reopening the project

all with no success.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Android Studio at the moment.  You can force the IDE to rebuild the relevant information by:

- removing a module from your `settings.gradle` file
- syncing
- adding the module back in
- syncing again

I don't know why this works, but it did for me.